# Bootstrap Modals

Tags: javascript, angular.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning how to implement Bootstrap modals in AngularJS. I can do it when the modal code (the actual popup window code) is on the main page, but I want to be able to display external files so that my SPA isn't super-cluttered.  I am implementing this on a much larger scale, but for simplicity's sake I'll keep the code example to a minimum.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- want this code to be an external.html file -->

    <div modal="showModal" close="cancel()">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.bootstrap.modal"]);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.showModal = true;
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.showModal = false;
  };

});
```

I know that I need to add a `templateUrl` to my app.js, but don't know how I would bridge the gap between the three files (index.html, app.js, and external.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the configuration for the modal:

From [Angular Bootstrap Documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

```
  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

Where your

```
templateUrl
```

attribute will be

```
external.html
```

Don't worry for how it works, you just should know that the modal library does it !